# Create https website with open SSL in PHP

Tags: php, ssl, openssl

I am currently learning PHP, and am making a web app with raw PHP for learning. 
Now I want to make my web app use https, and I found out about this thing called open SSL in PHP, but I could not find any examples of how exactly to use it to make my website https.

Is it possible to make my web app https with just using open SSL and not actually buying a certificate?

Comment: When you say raw PHP do you mean you're using PHP's web server or are you using something like Apache?

Comment: Even though PHP has access to the OpenSSL library, it's not PHP's job to handle SSL. You can't even if you wanted it to. This is something you should configure in your web server (such as Apache or IIS).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SSL is handled at the HTTP server level, not the PHP level. How you set up SSL depends on which HTTP server you use (e.g. Apache HTTPD).

You can set up SSL by [generating your own certificate](https://wiki.debian.org/Self-Signed_Certificate), but there will be no automatic chain of trust between browsers and you, so people will get a *dire security warning*. [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) offer free certificates.

Comment: I thought so, but then I just updated my wordpress site to the latest wordpress version, and it's now using SSL. How is this happening?

Answer (score 2):

SSL is configured at the *web server* level (Apache, Nginx, etc). As for avoiding the purchase of a certificate, you can use [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) to generate free certificates.

Comment: I thought so, but then I just updated my wordpress site to the latest wordpress version, and it's now using SSL. How is this happening?